# What's the best way to read a UDT from a database with Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, user-defined-types

I thought I knew everything about UDTs and JDBC until someone on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) pointed out some details of the Javadoc of [java.sql.SQLInput](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLInput.html) and [java.sql.SQLData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html) JavaDoc to me. The essence of that hint was (from SQLInput):

> An input stream that contains a stream
>   of values representing an instance of
>   an SQL structured type or an SQL
>   distinct type. This interface, used
>   only for custom mapping, is used by
>   the driver behind the scenes, and a
>   programmer never directly invokes
>   SQLInput methods.

This is quite the opposite of what I am used to do (which is also used and stable in productive systems, when used with the Oracle JDBC driver): Implement `SQLData` and provide this implementation in a custom mapping to

```
ResultSet.getObject(int index, Map mapping)
```

The JDBC driver will then call-back on my custom type using the

```
SQLData.readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName)
```

method. I implement this method and read each field from the `SQLInput` stream. In the end, `getObject()` will return a correctly initialised instance of my `SQLData` implementation holding all data from the UDT.

To me, this seems like the perfect way to implement such a custom mapping. Good reasons for going this way:

- I can use the standard API, instead of using vendor-specific classes such as `oracle.sql.STRUCT`, etc.
- I can generate source code from my UDTs, with appropriate getters/setters and other properties

**My questions**:

- What do you think about my approach, implementing `SQLData`? Is it viable, even if the Javadoc states otherwise?
- What other ways of reading UDT's in Java do you know of? E.g. what does Spring do? what does Hibernate do? What does JPA do? What do you do?

**Addendum**:

UDT support and integration with stored procedures is one of the major features of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). jOOQ aims at hiding the more complex "JDBC facts" from client code, without hiding the underlying database architecture. If you have similar questions like the above, jOOQ might provide an answer to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of configuring the driver so that it works behind the scenes is that the programmer does not need to pass the type map into ResultSet.getObject(...) and therefore has one less detail to remember (most of the time). The driver can also be configured at runtime using properties to define the mappings, so the application code can be kept independent of the details of the SQL type to object mappings. If the application could support several different databases, this allows different mappings to be supported for each database.

Your method is viable, its main characteristic is that the application code uses explicit type mappings.

In the behind the scenes approach the ResultSet.getObject(int) method will use the type mappings defined on the connection rather than those passed by the application code in ResultSet.getObject(int index, Map mapping). Otherwise the approaches are the same.

**Other Approaches**

I have seen another approach used with JBoss 4 based on these classes:

```
org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.JDBCParameterSetter 
org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.JDBCResultSetReader.AbstractResultSetReader
```

The idea is the same but the implementation is non-standard (it probably pre-dates the version of the JDBC standard defining SQLData/SQLInput).

Comment: I also found a post on an annotation-based approach used with TopLink: http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2007/12/oracle-spatial-and-toplink-11g.html

Comment: +1 for this interesting feedback, especially the JBoss approach. For my needs, the fact whether the type mapping is provided on each `getObject(...)` call or globally on the connection is a detail. There are pro's and cons to both approaches. In my case, I do not have control over the connection, as I am using this in a the jOOQ library (http://jooq.sourceforge.net). On the other hand, I hide concrete invocations on ResultSet from the library's client code... (example in http://tinyurl.com/3aaxdoj)

Answer (score 1):

> What other ways of reading UDT's in Java do you know of? E.g. what does Spring do? what does Hibernate do? What does JPA do? What do you do?

An example of how something similar to this can be done in Hibernate/JPA is shown in this answer to another question:

[Java Enums, JPA and Postgres enums - How do I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851758/java-enums-jpa-and-postgres-enums-how-do-i-make-them-work-together/857219#857219)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting feedback. Looks like a lot of manual work to do for just one single column, though...

Comment: Indeed, it's a lot of work. You can make it a little easier by using a smart base class with some defaults. The Hibernate API itself to do this surely is a little verbose.

Comment: It shows that my database interfacing library (http://jooq.sourceforge.net) does provide a solution to actual needs. I'm trying to tackle the problem with source code generation. The generated source code can then be easily and intuitively used as UDT's are supported natively.

Answer (score -2):

I know what Spring does: you write implementations of their [RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) interface.  I've *never* used SQLData with Spring.  Your post was the first time I'd ever heard of or thought about that interface.